# Lazarus Pascal - DB Connection - clarification

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, dbconnection

The following code is from the docs [here](http://wiki.freepascal.org/SqlDBHowto):

```
Program ConnectDB

var AConnection : TSQLConnection;

Procedure CreateConnection;
begin
  AConnection := TIBConnection.Create(nil);
  AConnection.Hostname := 'localhost';
  AConnection.DatabaseName := '/opt/firebird/examples/employee.fdb';
  AConnection.UserName := 'sysdba';
  AConnection.Password := 'masterkey';
end;

begin
  CreateConnection;
  AConnection.Open;
  if Aconnection.Connected then
    writeln('Succesful connect!')
  else
    writeln('This is not possible, because if the connection failed, ' +
            'an exception should be raised, so this code would not ' +
            'be executed');
  AConnection.Close;
  AConnection.Free;
end.
```

The main body of the code makes sense to me BUT I don't get where `TSQLConnection` came from. I cannot use **CTRL + Space** to autocomplete it either, which means my program has no reference to it. I'm trying to connect to Postgres by the way.

Can someone please state what `TSQLConnection` is? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `TSQLConnection` object is defined in the `sqldb` unit and is the base class for the specific connection components like the `TIBConnection` (interbase, firebird), `TConnectionName` (mysql) and `TPQConnection` (postgres).

Comment: If I included the pqconnection unit, shouldn't it come up as auto-complete? I don't get it.

Comment: No, to get the autocomplete feature you must include the unit where is defined the type in this case the `sqldb` unit.

Comment: @itsols what any ever relation do have PostGreSQL units to Firebird database server ??? Why do you have that idea to include **pq**connection.  PS. you can search for `Unified Interbase` component set - perhaps someone ported them to FPC as well.

Comment: @Arioch'The I only cited that block of code as a reference that had TSQLConnection. I'm not using FireBird. Rather it's postgres. I am aware of the other changes but I just couldn't relate TSQLConnection to the rest of the code as I got no auto-complete while typing it and did not know from which unit I should've used it.

Comment: @RRUZ Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I actually did something and it seems to work great. Instead of defining the db connection as TSQLConnection, I used PQConnection and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @RRUZ +1 for you :) I realised that when I added the Transaction component, it actually included the sqldb unit as well. So I decided to stick to using TSQLConnection instead of PQConnection. I hope this will make things easier... I'm trying to work it through code without using the visual components. Thanks!